# Scrapy Pagination Fails on Multiple Listing

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website using scrapy. 
When I scrape a specific page, pagination scraping works but when I try to scrape all the pages with one jump pagination does not work.
I tried creating an extra function for the pagination but this does not fix the problem. All help would be appreciated. What am I doing wrong ? Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.http import Request

from avtogumi.items import AvtogumiItem


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gumi'
    allowed_domains = ['avtogumi.bg']
    start_urls = ['https://bg.avtogumi.bg/oscommerce/index.php' ]

    def parse(self, response):

        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="brands"]//a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_params)


    def parse_params(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=AvtogumiItem(), response=response)

        l.add_xpath('title', '//h4/a/text()')
        l.add_xpath('subtitle', '//p[@class="ft-darkgray"]/text()')
        l.add_xpath('price', '//span[@class="promo-price"]/text()',
            MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
        l.add_xpath('stock', '//div[@class="product-box-stock"]//span/text()')
        l.add_xpath('category', '//div[@class="labels hidden-md hidden-lg"][0]//text()')
        l.add_xpath('brand', '//h4[@class="brand-header"][0]//text()', 
            MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
        l.add_xpath('img_path', '//div/img[@class="prod-imglist"]/@src')

        yield l.load_item()

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li/a[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse_params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is this:

```
l = ItemLoader(item=AvtogumiItem(), response=response)

l.add_xpath('title', '//h4/a/text()')
l.add_xpath('subtitle', '//p[@class="ft-darkgray"]/text()')
l.add_xpath('price', '//span[@class="promo-price"]/text()',
    MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
l.add_xpath('stock', '//div[@class="product-box-stock"]//span/text()')
l.add_xpath('category', '//div[@class="labels hidden-md hidden-lg"][0]//text()')
l.add_xpath('brand', '//h4[@class="brand-header"][0]//text()', 
    MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
l.add_xpath('img_path', '//div/img[@class="prod-imglist"]/@src')

yield l.load_item()
```

This snippet of code will parse and load exactly one result. If you have a page with multiple results, you would have to put this code inside a `for` loop and iterate over all the search results you want to parse:

```
objects = response.xpath('my_selector_here')
for object in objects:
    l = ItemLoader(item=AvtogumiItem(), response=response)

    l.add_xpath('title', '//h4/a/text()')
    l.add_xpath('subtitle', '//p[@class="ft-darkgray"]/text()')
    l.add_xpath('price', '//span[@class="promo-price"]/text()',
        MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
    l.add_xpath('stock', '//div[@class="product-box-stock"]//span/text()')
    l.add_xpath('category', '//div[@class="labels hidden-md hidden-lg"][0]//text()')
    l.add_xpath('brand', '//h4[@class="brand-header"][0]//text()', 
        MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
    l.add_xpath('img_path', '//div/img[@class="prod-imglist"]/@src')

    yield l.load_item()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @Woody1193 that fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

use/rewrite this code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gumi'
    allowed_domains = ['avtogumi.bg']
    start_urls = ['https://bg.avtogumi.bg/oscommerce/']

    def parse(self, response):   
        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="brands"]//a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url=response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_params)

    def parse_params(self, response):
        subjects = response.xpath('//div[@class="full-product-box search-box"]')
        for subject in subjects:
            yield {
                'title': subject.xpath('.//h4/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'subtitle': subject.xpath('.//p[@class="ft-darkgray"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'price': subject.xpath('.//span[@class="promo-price"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'stock': subject.xpath('.//div[@class="product-box-stock"]//span/text()').extract_first(),
                'category': subject.xpath('.//div[@class="labels hidden-md hidden-lg"][0]//text()').extract_first(),
                'brand': subject.xpath('.//h4[@class="brand-header"][0]//text()').extract_first(),
                'img_path': subject.xpath('.//div/img[@class="prod-imglist"]/@src').extract_first(),
            }
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li/a[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse_params)
```

> 13407 items scraped

[image]